# Weird behavior for nested labels in batch script

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Here is the batch program:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a incr=0

set arg1=%1
del test_output.csv > NUL 2>&1
del test_output.log > NUL 2>&1

set startTime=%time%
for /d %%i in ("%cd%\*") do call :run_test "%%i"
.\log_parser.exe
type test_output.csv
echo Start Time: %startTime%
echo Finish Time: %time%
exit /B

:run_test
  if not "%~nx1" == "shared" (
    echo Test: %~nx1
    cd %1

    del pass_fail_output.csv > NUL 2>&1
    echo Running...
    cd temp_root_fs
    start application.exe
    set /a incr=0
    :while1
      tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq application.exe" 2>NUL | find /i /n "application.exe">NUL
      if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
        if %incr% leq 60 (
          echo Still running...
          timeout /t 1 > NUL 2>&1
          set /a incr+= 1
          goto :while1
        )
        echo Test timed out...
        taskkill /im application.exe /f
      )
      echo Test completed...
    cd logs
    .\pass_fail_parser.exe
    type log.log >> ..\..\..\test_output.log
    copy pass_fail_output.csv ..\..\
    cd ..\..\
  )

  echo Cleaning...
  rmdir /S /Q temp_root_fs
  cd ..
)
```

This is my expected execution:

- Loop through folders
- Run the application
- Wait for 60 seconds and either kill the application after 60 seconds passes or continue if the application finishes
- Do some other executions to port log messages into an overall log file

The first loop works fine, but this is what my current output looks like when I execute it:

```
Test: test1
Initializing...
Running...
Still running...
Still running...
Still running...
Still running...
Still running...
Still running...
Still running...
Still running...
Still running...
Still running...
Test completed...
        1 file(s) copied.
Cleaning...
```

I know this is not working properly because I have 3 more folders for tests, so it should continue on to the other folders, but somehow it seems to break out of the for loop early.

I have read about the `/I` [option](https://jpsoft.com/help/goto.htm) that supposedly prevents the goto from breaking out of iff and do loops, but I am not entirely sure how it works (I tried adding it as a parameter but it either errors out or does not seem to do anything).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think including the actual batch contents would help. Do you mean that `goto :while1` is ignored? Are you by chance calling another batch file?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I added a bit more code. I realized it might be because I'm trying to use the label to potentially call a `taskkill` for an executable I'm running

Comment: So what is the last line that is executed? Did you try without the `@echo off` to clearly see what is executed?

Comment: You have a [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028), but you can avoid it with `if not errorlevel 1 goto :while1`. Every `goto` breaks the command block. There is nothing (especially no `/i`) to avoid that (and breaking the block isn't a problem with your code, as far as you have shown it).

Comment: Are you still missing lines? I get an error with `if defined run` (it expects the action after the condition), but even if that works for you, you are never undefining `run`. Are the quotes necessary in `"run=y"`? Why not just an `exit /b` after `taskkill`? If the application properly closes, you still get the timeout message and try to kill it.

Comment: @Andrew: `set "var=value"` is best practice; it avoids unwanted spaces and is safe against poison chars.

Comment: I added several more lines. I forgot that I am using `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` but I might not be using it properly (I think I need to do `!var!` instead of `%var%`). The primary problem is that the `:while1` label seems to break the outside for loop as well.

Comment: `I think I need to do !var! instead of %var%` - correct. `The primary problem is that the :while1 label seems to break the outside for loop as well` - correct. Goto breaks *all* code blocks/loops With the  now shown code, this *is* a problem. (The link you provided in your question is about another language, so the commands/parameters may behave different than `cmd`)

Comment: In my case the loop itself works fine (using the previous simplified batch code). I think you first need to clearly identify where the issue is. What I would do is: replace `application.exe` with something like `notepad.exe`, change the `start` with `echo start notepad.exe` and you just manually open one Notepad to avoid multiple annoying windows, use `leq 5` (or the like) instead, and also add an `echo` before `taskkill`. This way, you will verify that the whole logic goes though all the folders and waits 5 seconds. Finally, the `set /a incr=0` at line 3 can be removed.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I tried it out. It seems like what @Stephan said is what is happening: when I execute the `goto` at any point, it ultimately breaks all loops.

Comment: There is no `/I` option for `goto`, nor are there `iff` or `do loops`. That's TCC, not `cmd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:run_test
  if not "%~nx1" == "shared" (
    echo Test: %~nx1
    cd %1

    del pass_fail_output.csv > NUL 2>&1
    echo Running...
    cd temp_root_fs
    start application.exe
    set /a incr=0

    CALL :while1

    echo Test completed...
    cd logs
    .\pass_fail_parser.exe
    type log.log >> ..\..\..\test_output.log
    copy pass_fail_output.csv ..\..\
    cd ..\..\
  )

  echo Cleaning...
  rmdir /S /Q temp_root_fs
  cd ..
)

GOTO :EOF

:while1
  tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq application.exe" 2>NUL | find /i /n "application.exe">NUL
  if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    if %incr% leq 60 (
      echo Still running...
      timeout /t 1 > NUL 2>&1
      set /a incr+= 1
      goto :while1
    )
    echo Test timed out...
    taskkill /im application.exe /f
  )

GOTO :EOF
```

In your code, `if not "%~nx1" == "shared" (` to the final `)` is a `code block`. Labels are not permitted within a code block. The values `%var%` are replaced when the `if` statement is `parsed` by the values of those variables at that time, not as the change due to actions executed within the block. Beware of the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

The above code converts the `:while1` loop to an internal subroutine invoked by `CALL :while1` (the colon is *required* to indicate the call is to an internal label)

Note the `GOTO :EOF` statements. These transfer execution to the physical end-of-file (the colon is again, *required*) The first is to prevent execution from proceeding from `:run_test` into `:while1` by flow-through. The second is to force a return to the statement following `CALL :while1` when the `:while1` routine finishes. The `:while1` routine may be placed after *any* `goto` statement in the batch's mainline (ie. *not* a `goto` within a code block).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!